# regular expression not working as expected with the plus quantifier

Tags: regex

I have

> /\d+/

Using the string >"tom666tom"

It matches the 666. Shouldnt it fail when it hits the first t in tom?

How exactly is the regex engine working here. I know the plus sign means one or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it will fail if you tell the regex is should start and end with a number like so

```
/^\d+$/
```

the `^` defines the start of the string and `$` the end.

Comment: Why doesnt it fail at the first t?

Comment: because with regex you are able to match something in the string.
It's like saying, look for any pattern in this string and give me the results.

If you want the input string to match exactly to your pattern, you should add the start `^` and end `$` to your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern search one or more digits (+) in the input string

Comment: Yes, hence the question.

Comment: I understand, so you must to use `^` and `$` symbols

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling your expression to match the entire string. If any part of the string contains one or more digits, it will match. Use the `^` (zero-length start of line marker) and `$` (zero-length end of line marker) to delimit your regex and indicate that the only thing on the line should be digits: `/^\d+$/`.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't fall when it encounters first t in "tom" because a `+`

> matches 1 or more of the preceeding token. This is a greedy match, and
>   will match as many characters as possible before satisfying the next
>   token.

In your regex `/\d+/`, the `+` is placed after `\d` which matches any digit.

As said in the definition, the regex engine is working perfectly, because it is matching the previous token (`\d`) as many times it could.

So it will match the digits till it encounters a mismatch.

So the preceeding token here is `\d` and hence, regex engine is working fine.